# How do I make a local mysql server database accessible to the public with proper authentication

Tags: javascript, mysql

I currently have a mysql server on my local machine (which is on 24/7). 
It stores customer information such as name, address etc..
What is the correct way to allow the public to view their own personal data and make changes if neccessary, without leaking data?

I have considered using Firebase for authentication and creating login information within the database but **its the connection part im unsure about**.

Expectation: User gets given login details. User logs in and the server returns their information. User updates the information and the update is made on my local mysql server.

Comment: Where are the web pages located?

Comment: they will be hosted online.

Comment: you could setup a port forward on your firewall.  Assuming you have a static ip you then setup your web page to connect to yourip:3309  Authentication would be handled by your web app.  Not an optimal way to go tho.

Comment: whats not optimal? the authentication handled by the web app? what would you suggest?

Comment: Back to your original question. You either need a vpn connection between where your app is hosted and your local mysql machine or have your app connect to you static_ip:port. You would need a port forward on your local firewall/router.  You need to connect over SSL also. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encrypted-connections.html